# Is there a way to break a superordinate loop in C?

Tags: c, loops

Suppose you have two nested for loops like this:

```
int i, j;    // Iterators

for(i=0; i<100; ++i) {
     /* do some stuff */
     ...
     for(j=0; j<99; ++j) {
         /* do more stuff */
         ...
         if( someFunction(j,i) == 2 ) {
             /* break out of both loops */
         }
     }
}
```

Is there a way (similar to the `break;` command in just one loop) to end both loops on the spot?

Comment: `goto` is handy.

Comment: @robjb I doubt it is. This is one of the cases where `goto` is perfectly fine. Unconditional hatred towards `goto` is wrong.

Comment: you can refactor it to a function and call return

Comment: Absolutely not. This is C. As long as the goto jumps _completely_ out of both loops (and preferably _after_ them), it's acceptable. Jumping inside loops is a bit more controversial and hard to get right :) @robjb

Comment: @robjb it's not a joke; `goto` is the only way to do this and there is no non-dogmatic reason not to use it.

Comment: @SamHocevar: Not the *only* way, I would refactor to a function and use `return` as Hohhi suggested. That said, I was just checking. :)

Comment: user return to get out of the loops. You can use goto if you make it to go to a line outside of both the for loops

Comment: Returning from a function, as suggested by others, has always seemed the cleaner way to me, especially when the loops are not expected to complete in normal operation, eg. when searching for some match in lists of lists.  By 'cleaner', I mean 'easier to read' - a function named 'findMatchingEntry(ItemClass thisItem)' is easier to understand and debug than some goto thingy.  That, and later you often find that you need to call the lookup function from somewhere else..

Comment: Wow, thanks for the many swift and good answers. Damn you guys are fast!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use a `goto` as:

```
int i, j;    // Iterators

for(i=0; i<100; ++i) {
     /* do some stuff */
     ...
     for(j=0; j<99; ++j) {
         /* do more stuff */
         ...
         if( someFunction(j,i) == 2 ) {
             goto done;
         }
     }
}
done:
```

or use another variable to control the loop iterations:

```
int i, j;    // Iterators
int done = 0;
for(i=0; i<100 && !done; ++i) {
     /* do some stuff */
     ...
     for(j=0; j<99 && !done; ++j) {
         /* do more stuff */
         ...
         if( someFunction(j,i) == 2 ) {
             done = 1;
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: +1 for both ideas, although people don't like `goto`, it is faster than add to checks to each round.(as in your second options)

Comment: !done flag is verified each loop which is not that optimal it seems

Comment: +1 for the second idea. That's what I would do.
`goto` is faster, but is also dangerous. Strange things can occur if you don't pay a lot of attention while writing it.

The verification of the flag can be done only in the outer loop, add a `break` right after `done = 1;` and it will reduce the computational cost (Although it is very small for today computers)

Comment: @Victor I don't agree. The first variant is much easier to read, the second variant is much easier to get wrong. In this example it might not be much of a difference. But consider two or three loops that spans 50-100 lines. You don't have to check that !done is included in all the loops, you just have to place the label in the correct place.

Answer (score 5):

Our good friend `goto` can handle that for you!

```
int i, j;    // Iterators

for(i=0; i<100; ++i) {
     /* do some stuff */
     ...
     for(j=0; j<99; ++j) {
         /* do more stuff */
         ...
         if( someFunction(j,i) == 2 ) {
             /* break out of both loops */
             goto ExitLoopEarly;
         }
     }
}
goto ExitLoopNormal;

ExitLoopEarly:
....

ExitLoopNormal:
...
```

Answer (score 4):

That could be a solution

```
function void loop()
{
              int i, j;    // Iterators

            for(i=0; i<100; ++i) {
                 /* do some stuff */
                 ...
                 for(j=0; j<99; ++j) {
                     /* do more stuff */
                     ...
                     if( someFunction(j,i) == 2 ) {
                         return;
                     }
                 }
            }
}
```

Comment: This will only meet some cases, you ignore any value it may use inside the loops.

Comment: What do you mean? I can't really understand you

Comment: lets say he has three such double-loops in a function, and in those loops he modifies some local variables of the function, he will need to pass (by reference) each variable that is used in the loop to the function. goto or some flag seem much more reasonable.

Comment: Yes, but this is very much case specific and if you are working with more than one variable inside a loop there is a high probability that you can refactor it, so even in general case I can't think of an edge case that would stop you from using this implementation

Comment: Let me be more general - calling a function to avoid goto (and having its break with return in the middle) doesn't seem like advancement to me. that's all.

Comment: may be but it makes code readable, I agree it some kind of a hack but it is a nice hack rather than an ugly one

Answer (score 0):

You can insert two loops in a function and to use `return`

```
void foo(){
int i, j;    // Iterators

for(i=0; i<100; ++i) {
     /* do some stuff */
     ...
     for(j=0; j<99; ++j) {
         /* do more stuff */
         ...
         if( someFunction(j,i) == 2 ) {
             return;
         }
     }
}
}
```